# Appcelerator security and view issue

Tags: javascript, android, ios, xml, appcelerator

I am trying to publish to the Google Play store however there has been a security issue with appcelerator. `ti.modules.titanium.network.NonValidating TrustManager` This error will stop us from publishing to Google Play Store. From research i need to update the Titanium SDK to 5.2.0.GA or higher, this then brings me to my next problem.

I am currently running SDK 4.0.0.GA, as soon as i updated any higher the android version of the app crashes with the error `Cannot add window/tabGroup to a view` 
The error is self explanatory i just can't seem to get it working, if i change the HOME.XML to a view this works for android but makes the iOS not work. I would rather not recreate the views for each platform.

**HOMEGROUP.XML**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window platform="android" layout="vertical" onAndroidback="onAndroidBack" onOpen="onOpen" id="win">
        <View backgroundColor="#334488" height="Ti.UI.FILL" width="Ti.UI.FILL" id="tabContainer"></View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**HOME.XML**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="homeWindow" layout="horizontal">
        <View width="Ti.UI.SIZE" left="5">
            <Button id="Continue" onClick="Continue"/>
            <Button onClick="logOut" top="5">Log out</Button>
        </View>
        <View width="Ti.UI.FILL">
            <WebView id="Welcome"/>
        </View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: SDK 4.0.0 GA is very outdated and probably has all kind of wierd errors. You should really update the SDK, the current is 5.5.0 GA.

About the error, can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do thath would be helpful:) How are Homegroup.xml and home.xml related?

Comment: I ran into an issue similar to this as well.  I ended up with a system where I close the previous window after opening the tabgroup window.  My application was still in the development phase though and not an existing deployed app like yours.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue. We distributed our app with patched sdk for Ti 4.0.0 provided by appcelerator. Build your App with the patched sdk and the warning in playstore would go.

Refer:

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/03/update-on-recent-google-security-alerts/